# Timer внутри onPostExecute AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

хочу запустить таймер внутри функции onPostExecute... но почему то всегда падает программа ... каким способом можно исправить ?

```
        @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
                mTimerUpdate.cancel();
                mTimerUpdate.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d("QWER", "fdsfdsfdsdsss");
                    }
                }, 100, 100);
```

Comment: Таймер нужно пересоздать, после вызова метода `cancel()` таймер больше не может принимать задачи на выполнение. А еще есть такая штука как логи)

Comment: Спасибо! работает!

Comment: @SorryForMyEnglish Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий ответом.

Answer (score 1):

Таймер нужно пересоздать, после вызова метода `cancel()` таймер больше не может принимать задачи на выполнение.